# How to use copy/paste on ng-select custom tag

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement functionality as we have in Stackoverflow while asking new question, they are providing option to add multiple tags either by selecting options with mouse click or you can copy paste more than tags in one go.
[image]

I had created following sample code just to implement the same but I am not able select multiple items by pasting them in one go.
[Sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-hr5in1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please advise me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following code snippet to solve this issue:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Select multiple elements using paste</p>
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
<!-- <select style="width:200px;" [ngModel]="selectedSearchFilter" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel3">
              <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of searchFilters">{{i.name}}</option>
            </select> -->
    <ng-select style="width:300px;" [items]="searchFilters"
    [clearable]="false"
                                           bindLabel="name"
                                           bindValue="id"
                                           [(ngModel)]="selectedSearchFilter"
                                           (change)="onChange($event)">
                                </ng-select>         
    </div>
      <br>

   <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="personalForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div style="background-color: gainsboro">
    <div formArrayName="other" *ngFor="let other of personalForm.get('other').controls; let i = index"
        class="form-group"> 
 
        <div [formGroup]="other">
            <div class="form-group" class="row cols-md-12">
       <span for="filterName">{{other.controls.filterName.value}}</span>
                <ng-select #ngSelect formControlName="searchCreteria" 
      [items]="other.value.data" 
      [multiple]="true"
      [virtualScroll]="true"
                    bindLabel="name" 
        [closeOnSelect]="false" 
        [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
         bindValue="id"
                    (paste)="onPaste($event,other,i)" 
        (clear)="removeCompletePanel(i)" 
        [selectOnTab]="true"
                    [closeOnSelect]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedSearchCreteria[i]">
                    <!-- <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
                        <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [ngModel]="item$.selected" id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox"/> {{item.name | uppercase}}
        </ng-template> -->
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index">
                        <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [ngModel]="item.selected" id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox"/> {{item.name | uppercase}}
        </ng-template>
                </ng-select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
       (click)="onClearDataClick()">Clear Data</button>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
       (click)="onShowSelectedItemsClick()">Show Selected items</button>
</form>

{{finalValues | json}}
```

**TS:**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService, Person } from "../data.service";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormArray,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "multi-checkbox-example",
  templateUrl: "./multi-checkbox-example.component.html"
})
export class MultiCheckboxExampleComponent implements OnInit {
 
  selectedSearchCreteria = [];
  ngSelectCount = [];
  personalForm: FormGroup;

  searchFilters = [
    { name: "--Please Select Item--", id: -1 },
    { name: "Country", id: 1 },
    { name: "States", id: 2 },
    { name: "Cities", id: 3 }
  ];
  selectedSearchFilter = this.searchFilters[0].id;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      filter: new FormControl(null),
      other: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  addOtherSkillFormGroup(filterName: string): FormGroup {
    let data = this.getDropData(filterName);
    let groupData = {
      filterName:[filterName],
      searchCreteria: [""],
      data: [data]
    };
    //groupData['data']=data;
    return this.formBuilder.group(groupData);
  }

  onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent, controlData: any, i: any) {
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
    let pastedData = clipboardData.getData("text");
    // split using new line
    var queries = pastedData.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
    // iterate over each part and add to the selectedItems
    queries.forEach(q => {
      var cnt = controlData.value.data.find(
        i => i.name.toLowerCase() === q.trim().toLowerCase()
      );
      if (cnt != undefined) {
        this.selectedSearchCreteria[i] = [...this.selectedSearchCreteria[i], cnt.id];
      }
    });
    let nodes: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.querySelectorAll(
      ".ng-input input"
    ) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
    for (let i = 0; nodes[i]; i++) {
      (nodes[i] as HTMLElement).blur();
    }
  }

  onClearDataClick() {
    (<FormArray>this.personalForm.get("other")).clear();
    this.ngSelectCount.length = 0;
    this.selectedSearchFilter = this.searchFilters[0].id;
    this.selectedSearchCreteria.length = 0;
  }
  onChange(e) {
    if (e.id != -1) {
      var cnt = this.ngSelectCount.find(i => i === e.id);
      if (cnt == undefined) {
        (<FormArray>this.personalForm.get("other")).push(
          this.addOtherSkillFormGroup(e.name)
        );
        this.selectedSearchCreteria.push([]);
        this.ngSelectCount.push(e.id);
        this.selectedSearchFilter = e.id;
      }
    } else {
      (<FormArray>this.personalForm.get("other")).clear();
      this.ngSelectCount.length = 0;
      this.selectedSearchFilter = this.searchFilters[0].id;
      this.selectedSearchCreteria.length = 0;
    }
  }

  removeCompletePanel(e) {
    (<FormArray>this.personalForm.get("other")).removeAt(e);
    this.ngSelectCount.splice(e, 1);
    this.selectedSearchFilter = this.searchFilters[0].id;
    this.selectedSearchCreteria.splice(e, 1);
  }

  onShowSelectedItemsClick() {
    let output:any = "";
    (<FormArray>this.personalForm.get("other")).controls.forEach(function(formControl) {
      formControl.value["searchCreteria"].forEach(q => {
        var cnt = formControl.value.data.find(i => i.id === q);
        //console.log(formControl.value["filterName"]+'--'+cnt.name);
        output = output + formControl.value["filterName"]+'--'+cnt.name+','
      });
    });
    alert(output);
  }

  getDropData(filterType: string) {
    if (filterType == "Country") {
      return [
        { id: 1, name: "India" },
        { id: 2, name: "Switzerland" },
        { id: 3, name: "Norway" },
        { id: 4, name: "Macao" },
        { id: 5, name: "Qatar" },
        { id: 6, name: "Ireland" },
        { id: 7, name: "United States" },
        { id: 15, name: "United Kingdom" },
        { id: 21, name: "United Arab Emirates" }
      ];
    } else if (filterType == "States") {
      return [
        { id: 1, name: "State 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "State 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "State 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "State 4" },
        { id: 5, name: "State 5" },
        { id: 6, name: "State 6" },
        { id: 7, name: "State 7" },
        { id: 15, name: "State 8" },
        { id: 21, name: "State 9" }
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        { id: 1, name: "City 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "City 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "City 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "City 4" },
        { id: 5, name: "City 5" },
        { id: 6, name: "City 6" },
        { id: 7, name: "City 7" },
        { id: 15, name: "City 8" },
        { id: 21, name: "City 9" }
      ];
    }
  }
  /////////////////////////////
}
```

For live example please check following link [Angular MultiSelect](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmhb9v-3pk4nj?file=src%2Fmulti-checkbox-example.component.ts)